# Why View.onDisappear not get called?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In iOS 13 beta 4, all View.onDisappear do not get called.

There is a navigation view and push to a Detail View. When a user tap navigation back button, the DetailView.onDisappear not get called.
How to fix it?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) { Text("show") }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("here")
            .onDisappear {
                print("onDisappear")
            }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: It’s likely a bug as it’s beta. Suspect it to be fixed as the betas get released. It’s probably wise to play with SwiftUI but not yet (whilst in beta) to use in a real app.

Answer (score 6):

In the current beta `onAppear()` works great but `onDisappear()` doesn’t seem to get called.

Comment: This is still an issue on iOS 13.5; `onDisappear()` IS NOT reliable.